# Is this the right MVC Application Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

**Requirements:**

1.A page showing list of id's from the database.

2.Once the user clicked the item ID in the list, a modal will pop up showing all details from that id

**Problem:**
MVC seems to required another URL in order to use the selected id that cause redirection from another page showing the id details
Solution:
so what i did is put the list into a partial view and call the `partialview` in another page pretending that it didn't redirects.

**Question:**
Am I doing it the right way or a dirty way?
Do MVC behave this way? 
If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Its got nothing to do with MVC - if you don't want to redirect, then the information must exist in the view (and you use javascript to show it), or you use ajax to call a controller method that return the information for the pop-up and display it in the success callback

Answer (score 0):

this is not the mvc issue, if you want to popup a modal window to show the detail information, there are many ways can do that, this is the javascript issue, you can use [jquery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [sweet alert2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) or others js lib for that.